# AppleScript to remove last three letters from a file name, preserving extension

Tags: finder, applescript, macos

I'm using some software that outputs files of the format

```
abcdefg#01.wav
abcdefg#02.wav
abcdefg#03.wav
```

and so on.

I'd like to create a Quick Action in Automator to use in Finder to remove the #, and everything after the #, but preserving the file extension.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What about the leading space you are showing in front of the `#` character, do what that removed also? What have to tried so far?

Comment: I've googled it a fair bit but I'm not by anyone's standards a programmer. I found a script that removes the numbers but not the #:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3366373

Comment: Also, I just checked and in fact there is no leading space - thanks for making me check that!

Comment: Your example _filenames_ show a leading _space_ in front of the `#` _character_! Please edit your question to reflect accurate information.

Comment: I didn't  test the _code_ in the link of your comment, however,  the `sed` _command_ to remove e.g. `#01` in `abcdefg#01.wav` and similar _patterns_ would be: `sed -E 's/[#0-9]+//'`

Comment: Thanks, user3439894, that worked great. For anyone following this breadcrumb trail in the future, use the script I linked to and replace the part of the code starting with sed to the bit of script that the above comment has helpfully suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In a new Automator Quick Action Workflow, you’ll want to set the initial properties so that the workflow accepts files and folders as input, and select *Finder* as the application to which this workflow is applicable.

Add a single action to the workflow.  There are two good choices, and which you choose is up to you.  I recommend the **Run Shell Script** action for its speed and compactness, but the **Run AppleScript** action will likely be easier for you to adapt to other situations in the future:

#### 1) Run Shell Script :

- If your preferred shell is `zsh` or `bash`, or one of these options is present in the list, then you can use the code below with the following parameters selected for the action:

  <sup>→ **Shell:** `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/bash`

   → **Input:** *`as arguments`*</sup>

  Check the path to the chosen shell matches the shebang (`#!/path/to/shell`) on the first line of this script, editing it as required:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/zsh

  alias rename=echo
  # alias rename='mv -n'

  for f in "$@" ; do
       rename "$f" "${f%#*}.${f##*.}"
  done
  ```

  This script is safe to run "as is", as it will not perform any file operations just yet.  It will print each filepath followed by the proposed path of the renamed file on a single line, one line per file.  If the result looks good, you can remove the `#` preceding `alias rename='mv -n'`, after which, any susbsequent invocation of the script will perform the file operations that will rename the files.

---

- If you use `FiSH` as your preferred shell, select it from the list of options, and apply the following parameters to the action (the path to your `FiSH` shell may be different, e.g. *`/usr/local/bin/fish`*):

  <sup>→ **Shell:** `/usr/bin/fish`

   → **Input:** *`as arguments`*</sup>

  Edit the shebang on the first line to reflect the actual path to `FiSH`:

  ```sh
  #!/usr/bin/fish

  function mv
       echo $argv \n
  end

  for filepath in $argv
      mv -n "$filepath" ( string replace -r \
                          -- '(?x) \# [0-9]+ 
                              (?=\.[^.]+$)' \
                             '' "$filepath" )
  end
  ```

  This is safe to run "as is", and will only print the proposed renaming next to the original filepath, one per line for each file.  If it looks good, you can delete the function declaration, namely these three lines:

  ```
  function mv
       echo $argv \n
  end
  ```

  after which, any subsequent invocation of the script will act upon the files and rename them accordingly.

#### 2) Run AppleScript:

- Replace any sample code that is present in the editing pane, and replace it with the following:

  ```
  property text item delimiters : "#"

  on run {filepaths}
      tell application id "com.apple.systemevents"
          repeat with filepath in the filepaths
              tell the item named filepath
                  set {filename, extension} to its {name, name extension}
                  tell the extension to if its length > 0 ¬
                      then set the extension to "." & it

                  if "#" is in the filename then set its name to ¬
                      "" & (the filename's text items 1 thru -2) ¬
                      & the extension
               end tell
          end repeat
      end tell
  end run
  ```

  I recommemd testing this on some dummy files initially to make sure it does what you expected.  I haven't the means to test this code, which I would normally do, although even if I had, it's always advisable to test any code you didn't write yourself beforehand.

Comment: Hi CJK, thanks for the suggestions. I tried both of these and neither of them worked straight away. Not being a programmer, I didn't try to work out why, especially since an earlier commenter's suggestion did work. Really appreciate the help though. What a great community!

Comment: I'd have been surprised if they had. But, to help me get them working, can you tell me in what ways they didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

AppleScript:

```
set input to "atttttttbcde#09.wav"
set output to (do shell script "myVar=\"" & input & "\" && basenameVar=\"${myVar%#*}\" && echo \"$basenameVar.${myVar##*.}\" ")
```

Shell script (must use Args in Automator to fill in var)

```
myVar=(Enter Shell arg here) && basenameVar="${myVar%#*}" && echo "$basenameVar.${myVar##*.}"
```

Works well. It not only removes 2-digit numbers and #, it also removes all characters after the # and then adds back the extension (that it stored in a var earlier).

Heres a deeper explanation:

1. Stores original filename as Var in ZSH
2. Takes out anything after # from original name
3. Adds back extension, which is found from original name\
4. Echoes out the final name, which is stored into the output variable in applescript

Comment: Erm…  Why the AppleScript?  Yes, the title of the question says AppleScript.  The OP states he just wants an Automator Quick Action.  So a shell script would be infinitely more appropriate.

Comment: Oh! It’s just a shell script wrapped in AppleScript, so it’s easy to convert.

Comment: “Easy” is relative, and if the OP is asking for help to make a Quick Action, I shouldn’t think he’ll be boshing out code and converting between languages.  But, that’s my two cents, and I appreciate your take is different, and it means I won’t be stepping on your toes by contributing a pure shell script solution.

Comment: I already did make it a shell script.

Comment: I haven't tried this since an earlier commenter's suggestion worked for me, but I really appreciate it!